# Responses tab on activity page doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Recently (the last couple days) the ["responses" tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses)<sup>*</sup> on my activity page is dead.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Link will (try to) take you to **your** responses tab.</sub>

Comment: The same with me.

Comment: Hmmm... I've been able to load yours, @bof. It took a little while to load, but it did. Wasn't able to load my own. Got the [error page](http://math.stackexchange.com/error), part of which states "Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified. ¶ Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them." Not entirely encouraging.

Comment: Responses tab works for me on MathOverflow and meta.SE. Both on math.SE and meta I am getting error at the moment.

Comment: Until the issue is fixed, you could use the [global inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) as a workaround. (The link works for me. And maybe you can test by checking it, whether you are receiving notifications from meta;.math.SE there.)

Comment: I asked about this [in chat yesterday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29885839#29885839). It is still a problem for me.  The [global inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox), mentioned by Martin Sleziak, works.

Comment: I'll be looking at this tomorrow (Friday). Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 4):

We have now deployed some changes to the affected code, and it should work a lot better today (actually, Nick Craver had already done the work to change this - we just hadn't deployed it yet).